# "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically" in jupyter with big DB

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-lab, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I am using jupyter and i have a problem with compiling the following code:

```
matrix1, matrix2 = tfidf.prova(data['post_corpus'], ["problem loading csv file"])
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(matrix1, matrix1)
```

When the compiler executes the second line of code, I am shown the following message:

"The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

However, I have noticed that if I use

```
matrix1, matrix2 = tfidf.prova(data['post_corpus'].head(10), ["problem loading csv file"])
```

no problem arises. So since data contains a very large db, I assumed that the problem is related to the size of data.
Is this assumption correct? If so, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check the log stream of jupyter, it may contain more info on what went wrong

Comment: Your assumption is likely correct. Very likely it is your operating system terminating the process because you are running out of memory. Try running some memory usage diagnostics and observe how it changes when it crashes.